# Include paths and functions for external scripts

Tags: plugins, include, paths, plugin-options

I try load external script as plugin , the idea it´s use one easy plugin and call script and load this script into admin but i have problems with some configuration files and css files , in the case of css files for example load and the path it´s right but no add the styles to the forms , by other side i have one file of configuration for insert some strings and take values as the type as this :

```
$path="../configuration";
```

The problem it´s no take the values of this string or other

My functions this :

```
if (is_admin())
{
  function load_libraries()
  {
    locate_template(array('core/funciones/funciones_config.php'), true,false);
  }
  ?>
  <?php
  function plugin_admin_options_page() {
    add_action('admin_menu', 'load_libraries');
    echo $ruta_path;
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>Plugin Options Admin Page</h2>
      <?php
      locate_template(array('core/modulos/mod_dominios/index_adm_menu.php'), true,true);
      ?>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
  //add_options_page("Dominios", "sistema de dominios", "administrator", "dominios_options", "plugin_admin_options_page");
  ?>
  <?php
  function searcher_domains() 
  {
    //add_options_page('Hello World', 'Hello World', 'administrator','hello-world', 'hello_world_html_page');
    add_options_page('Dominios', 'Dominios', 'administrator', 'adm_dominios', 'plugin_admin_options_page');
  }
  add_action('admin_menu', 'searcher_domains');
}
```

The idea it´s load external scripts into admin of WordPress for manage the same other plugins but the real problem it´s with the paths and include this kind of files and also css or js from this little plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding exactly what the problem is but two things come to mind.

1. [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) searches [*theme* directories](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/template.php#L373). It is not
   a general purpose file loader. I don't know if that is relevant to
   your case. There is not enough detail in the question to work that
   out. Given that you have not mentioned themes at all and are only talking about "external scripts" and plugins, I suspect that this is the problem.
2. You [may be having *scope* issues](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) with the includes.